# Unable to call ToArray() on 3rd party class

Tags: c#, linq

I was planning on using some LINQ on a 3rd party class (Kentico) but seem unable to do so and I can't figure out why. My code is essentially:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
// some additional namespaces

namespace test
{
   public partial class ProductFilter : CMSAbstractBaseFilterControl
   {
       protected IEnumerable<String> GetCategories(String parentName)
        {
            CategoryInfo info = CategoryInfoProvider.GetCategoryInfo(parentName, CMSContext.CurrentSite.SiteName);
            var children = CategoryInfoProvider.GetChildCategories(info.CategoryID, null, null, -1, null, CMSContext.CurrentSite.SiteID);

            children.ToArray();
        }
   }
```

At this point I get the error

> Error 5   'CMS.SettingsProvider.InfoDataSet'
>   does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method
>   'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type
>   'CMS.SettingsProvider.InfoDataSet'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

CategoryInfoProvider.GetChildCategories is defined as:

```
public static InfoDataSet<CategoryInfo> GetChildCategories(int categoryId, string where, string orderBy, int topN, string columns, int siteId);
```

InfoDataSet is defined as:

```
public class InfoDataSet<InfoType> : ObjectDataSet<BaseInfo>, IEnumerable<InfoType>, IInfoDataSet, IEnumerable where InfoType : CMS.SettingsProvider.BaseInfo, new()
{
    public InfoDataSet();
    public InfoDataSet(DataSet sourceData);

    public InfoObjectCollection<InfoType> Items { get; protected set; }
    protected InfoType Object { get; set; }

    public InfoDataSet<InfoType> Clone();
    public IEnumerator<InfoType> GetEnumerator();
    public InfoType GetNewObject(DataRow dr);
    protected override ObjectCollection<BaseInfo> NewCollection();
}
```

It looks like the interfaces are implemented correctly, I've got the namespace included for LINQ and I can make calls like `List<int> i; i.ToArray();` What piece to the puzzle am I missing?

Comment: Can you foreach over children?

Comment: @FlorianDohrendorf: I can foreach yes

Comment: Try `IEnumerable<CategoryInfo> children` instead of `var children`... Also try "go to definition/implementation" on that `GetChildCategories` call and see if it finds what you expect.

Comment: Your code will not compile because you don't have a return statement. Maybe you can post the compilable example?

Comment: @nvoigt Sorry - just take out the return. Unless you install Kentico which I don't recommend I can't give you compatible code. I never got to the return because I couldn't form my LINQ statement.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: That seems to work - could you post an answer and explain why?

Comment: I expected it to fail due to picking wrong "GetChildCategories" method... No idea why it did actually work... What `childern.GetType()` was when it used "var"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: CMS.SettingsProvider.InfoDataSet<InfoType> . The thing is method resolution doesn't take return type into account so I'm not sure that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try slipping in a call to `AsEnumerable()`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
// some additional namespaces

namespace test
{
   public partial class ProductFilter : CMSAbstractBaseFilterControl
   {
       protected IEnumerable<String> GetCategories(String parentName)
        {
            CategoryInfo info = CategoryInfoProvider.GetCategoryInfo(parentName, CMSContext.CurrentSite.SiteName);
            var children = CategoryInfoProvider.GetChildCategories(info.CategoryID, null, null, -1, null, CMSContext.CurrentSite.SiteID);

            children.AsEnumerable().ToArray();
        }
   }
}
```

The problem seems to be that the compiler cannot resolve `children` as an IEnumerable, even though the collection explicitly implements the interface. Forcing the collection to be treated as an IEnumerable, which AsEnumerable does, should allow ToArray to be properly resolved.

Comment: I actually tried AsEnumerable() and it complained in exactly the same way.

Comment: Did you try explicitly defining the collected type? If ObjectDataSet also implements the generic IEnumerable, then there may be an ambiguity between the base and derived implementation; `children` would be both an `IEnumerable<BaseInfo>` and `IEnumerable<InfoType>` and it may not be clear to the compiler which to use. Try `AsEnumerable<InfoType>()` and see what happens. If that works, try simply `ToArray<InfoType>()`.

Comment: I have tried switching from var to IEnumerable<CategoryInfo> as per Alexis' comment which does compile.