# NullReferenceException when trying to Enumerate via Mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, kentico, justmock

I'm getting an odd NullReferenceException that I can't understand when trying to mock up a collection to enumerate. I don't think it's anything caused by Mock but I'm not 100% sure. Can anyone identify anything silly that I'm doing?

```
InfoDataSet<OrderItemInfo> orders = OrderItemInfoProvider.GetOrderItems(orderInfo.OrderID);
foreach (OrderItemInfo orderItem in orders)
{
    // Exception thrown on the first attempt to get an OrderItem in the foreach
}
```

The stack trace from this line of code is the following:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. Result StackTrace:   at
>   CMS.SettingsProvider.ObjectDataSet`1.GetEnumerator()    at
>
>   CMS.SettingsProvider.ObjectDataSet`1.GetObjectEnumerator()    at
>   CMS.SettingsProvider.InfoDataSet`1.d__0.MoveNext()
>   at ...

The content of the collection is simply a wrapper around an IEnumerable. In my case this should give you an idea on what is going on. GetEnumerator (both implicit and none implicit) implementations simply call through to values.

```
    private IEnumerable<T> values;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MockDataSet{T}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="values">The values.</param>
    public MockDataSet(IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        if (values == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("values");

        this.values = values;
    }
```

Values has a single value in it, that I can enumerate fine via the watch window...

[image]

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @lan why dont you show some code inside the foreach. That would give us something more to think on.

Comment: @Dinesh: I can - although I never get as far as that code and it's domain specific. I've actually just located the problem... will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of an odd one this that I think is partially down to the CMS underneath (Kentico). I came across a problem earlier which I posted a question on [Unable to call ToArray() on 3rd party class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640605/unable-to-call-toarray-on-3rd-party-class) and I just realised this could be having the same affect.

It seems that the result of `InfoDataSet<OrderItemInfo> orders = OrderItemInfoProvider.GetOrderItems(orderInfo.OrderID);` is difficult for the compiler to determine the type of. Therefore I think a cast is occuring underneath say

`((IEnumerable<OrderItemInfo>)orders)`

I believe this is failing, causing the IEnumerable to be null, and hence the NullReferenceException. The resolution is a simple cast of each item:

```
InfoDataSet<OrderItemInfo> orders = OrderItemInfoProvider.GetOrderItems(orderInfo.OrderID);
foreach (OrderItemInfo orderItem in orders.Cast<OrderItemInfo>())
{
   // Now works
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`orders` is null.  You are thinking it is not because the loop has started but remember this is evaluated lazy.

Change the code like this, it won't fail:

```
InfoDataSet<OrderItemInfo> orders = OrderItemInfoProvider.GetOrderItems(orderInfo.OrderID);
if (orders != null)
{
  foreach (OrderItemInfo orderItem in orders)
  {
      // Exception thrown on the first attempt to get an OrderItem in the foreach
  }
}
```

Remember too, whenever you look at something in the debugger a long time has passed in cycles time -- if you have any async updating it might not have finished.

Comment: I'm afraid orders isn't null... As shown in the watch it is populated. I tried the null reference checking and it fails in exactly the same way (note that I removed the watch before running my test).

Comment: @Ian - Oh, if you posted an image I can't see it.  (Firewall).  You have code exactly like above?  What is the first attempt to use orderItem look like?

Comment: Hogan - about to post an answer as to why. Sorry yes I did include an image